# Alternative idiom for 'get your foot out of your mouth'?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

So... "take your foot out of your mouth" is an interesting idiom. It's an admonishment (both a scolding and a recommendation) for when someone says something unintentionally insensitive; roughly, "think before you speak", but noting not just that the speaker failed to do so, but that what they said was offensive, not just unintended.

Is there any *other* idiomatic phrase that has an equivalent meaning? ("Think before you speak" isn't idiomatic. Nothing else is coming to mind.)

Comment: Answers in comments have been deleted. Do not under any circumstances do so again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139077/discussion-between-matthew-and-robbie-goodwin).

Answer (score 3):

When you're in a hole, stop digging

Meaning, when you've already created a problem, stop, don't continue doing the same thing to make it worse.

From the Washington Post, 1911.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_holes

Comment: Yes, I think it's mainly used to address conversation. It's appeared here before in a more general context

Answer (score 1):

Though not idioms, these phrases are commonly used and means the same thing.

Don't embarrass yourself any further (by talking)

Stop talking and do yourself a (great) service

Shut your "trap"/"pie hole" (it may be considered an idiom)

Answer (score -1):

A similar admonishment is **Look before you leap**. It is relevant, although not specific, to speaking. Because it relies on an analogy between acting without thought of consequence and leaping (off a height, over a gap, into the dark, etc) without attention to the danger, it is not literal, and is entirely idiomatic.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-before-you-leap)
> to check that something is not going to cause problems or have a bad result before you do it

Comment: Would the Downvoter care to explain to the Questioner why this answer is so bad? Or was it mere pique? I am intrigued.

Comment: I didn't DV, but this is not only not specific to speech, it's not really about doing something inappropriate. Also, "take your foot out of your mouth" is said *after* the inappropriate action has taken place, while "look before you leap" is general advice in advance.